# Can i use the row result of a query to run a sub query and get the data returned?

Tags: mysql, node.js

**to be clear I want to avoid for loop in my node.js program**

my current approach is a group_concat() query [which is working correctly]

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(c.main), GROUP_CONCAT(c.cId) AS cId_List FROM customers c LEFT JOIN boxes b ON b.boxId = c.boxId WHERE c.opId = ? GROUP BY c.conNo ORDER BY c.conNo ASC;
//response to json
    {
      "main": 2,
      "cId_List": "512,513"
    },{
      "main": 3,
      "cId_List": "514,515,516,517"
    },....
```

The next query i need to run is for every "cId_List"

```
for(every cId_List){
  qry = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payments p WHERE p.cId IN (cId_List);"
}
```

how can I avoid it?

Reasons to avoid it is because there is no limit to no.queries. It Can be 10000+ at a single request.

Added Info

**What is happening?**

There is are two tables namely customers, payments

There can be multiple rows in customer table with same "connection number [main]"

 by doing group concat I am getting the ids of those rows into cId_List

 now for every cId_List I want to run the SUM() Query in payments Table

 so my result shall be

```
{
          "main": 2,
          "cId_List": "512,513", //multiple rows of customers table
          "amount_sum": 500 //data from payments table using above cId_List
        },{
          "main": 3,
          "cId_List": "514,515,516,517",
          "amount_sum": -200
        },....
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a65cf6)

as asked: sqlfiddle explanation
customers.conNo is a unifying column for multiple customers *(basically of a family, they are billed together)*
customers.cId is the primary key and the separator factor *(when we need to bill per person basis)*

payments.cId is foreign key of customers.cId and payments are entered as per cId

report needs to be generated according to conNo

so to get all the payments of a conNo I need to send all the appropriate cId to payments table.

I hope this will clear the doubts.

**EDIT:**

I am checking this query which may be the answer, I would like to know if this query format is good performance wise?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(customers.cId)) AS cId_List, customers.*, payments.cId, SUM(amount) AS amt FROM `payments` left join customers on customers.cId = payments.cId GROUP BY `customers`.`conNo` ORDER BY `customers`.`conNo` ASC
```

Comment: it does work and it works perfectly, it is not important
I dont want to get rid of the GRUOP_BY it is fine.
I want to get rid of the 'for' loop that will come next.

Comment: @strawberry please check edits, if you still want I can provide create and inserts

Comment: for some reasons http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63e2d5 I am unable to execute any query in this

Comment: i removed boxes, it will be irrelevant. All I need is to run a 'payment' query per cId_List

Comment: it is not duplicate, the php question is pretty simply a JOIN statement, mine has to be used with a group_concat.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I must have read too quickly.

Comment: However you will need to [explain what `conNo` contains](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2349963/rohit-hazra) as well as all other columns in your SQLFiddle. Also, the values in your fiddle does not match the ones in your example above, and your above queries do not run there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that you can simply replace all of your code with the following:

```
 SELECT c.conno
      , SUM(p.amount) total
   FROM customers c
   LEFT
   JOIN payments p
     ON p.cid = c.cid
  GROUP
     BY c.conno
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a65cf6/11

Comment: no i cant, u r missing `cId_List`  multiple rows of customer table make up cId_list and that cId_list will get sum from multiple rows of payments table.

Comment: your query gives me this as response: http://imgur.com/x9Hcxh8 now what i need is that all the same conNo comes in one row so for first row it will be +50 and there will be only 3 rows.

Comment: your query is working perfectly, I would like to know which of these is more correct approach if they are different? second being my answer which is correct by the way i dont know why it was downvoted http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a65cf6/13 this one i mean, it is just getting a little extra data

Comment: Your query selects all columns from the customers table (*), but only aggregates on the `conno` column. This means that it returns random/meaningless data for `cid`. The cid_list itself also seems redundant in this instance.

Comment: @RohitHazra Also, your query LEFT JOINs customers on to payments. This is nonsensical because while there may be customers without payments there will NEVER be payments without customers. It just so happens that in your data set there is at least one payment associated with each customer.

Comment: Thank You, I didnt think of it at all. 
I have accepted your answer as correct one.
Really thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(p.amount)
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN payments AS p ON p.cid = c.cid
GROUP BY c.cid
```

Comment: The OP wants one sum per cId_List. Close though.

Comment: creating fiddle, provide me a little time need to run a quick errand

Comment: no i cant, u r missing `cId_List`  multiple rows of customer table make up cId_list and that cId_list will get sum from multiple rows of payments table.

Answer (score -1):

This query seems to work. Can any one tell me if it is appropriate performance wise.
 Also would like your suggestions if any
 Thanks to @Strawberry and @Luca Giardina

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(customers.cId)) AS cId_List, 
customers.*, payments.cId, 
SUM(amount) AS amt 
FROM `payments` LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.cId = payments.cId 
GROUP BY `customers`.`conNo` 
ORDER BY `customers`.`conNo` ASC
```

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is NO problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is (part of) the solution. This is no exception. You just need a JOIN, and a SUM...GROUP BY